# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\kudo\01_Work\Repos\expo\expo\android\versioned-react-native

Tags: react-native, expo

I have upgraded expo from 46 to 47 and enabled hermes on app.json

now I get this error message

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\kudo\01_Work\Repos\expo\expo\android\versioned-react-native\ReactAndroid\hermes-engine\.cxx\MinSizeRel\2q85j1u4\arm64-v8a\lib\InternalBytecode\InternalBytecode.js'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
    at getCodeFrame (C:\xxx\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1028:18)
    at Server._symbolicate (C:\xxx\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1101:22)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Server._processRequest (C:\xxx\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:458:7) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\kudo\\01_Work\\Repos\\expo\\expo\\android\\versioned-react-native\\ReactAndroid\\hermes-engine\\.cxx\\MinSizeRel\\2q85j1u4\\arm64-v8a\\lib\\InternalBytecode\\InternalBytecode.js'
}
```

This happend when I dispatch anything with RTK Query

Only happens on Android.

env info

```
expo-env-info 1.0.5 environment info:
System:
OS: Windows 10 10.0.19044
Binaries:
Node: 16.13.2 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
Yarn: 1.22.11 - ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD
npm: 8.1.2 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
IDEs:
Android Studio: Version 2020.3.0.0 AI-203.7717.56.2031.7583922
npmPackages:
expo: ^47.0.0 => 47.0.8
react: 18.1.0 => 18.1.0
react-dom: 18.1.0 => 18.1.0
react-native: 0.70.5 => 0.70.5
react-native-web: ~0.18.7 => 0.18.8
Expo Workflow: managed
```

Comment: can you create a minimal reproducible example and post it to https://github.com/expo/expo/issues please?

Comment: @brentvatne the problem is in expo snack app.json does not exists so I can not enable hermes on expo snack. Or can it be done ? If you solve this problem I can give you money

Comment: you don't need to use snack for a minimal reproducible example, you can share a project on github